# GNU sed: append both BEFORE name start and AFTER name end (output is: "$ ls -xN")

Tags: sed, regular-expression, newlines, whitespace

Please could someone check if my GNU `sed` script is the nice way to do it or if it's some sort of bad / wrong hack :p

```
$ ls -xN
1
2
3
4
```

```
$ ls -xN | sed -E "s/(.{1})$/\1\.log/" | sed -E "s/^(.{1})/Day\ \1/"
Day 1.log
Day 2.log
Day 3.log
Day 4.log
```

I can't understand why `sed` does not recognize `\n` (*newline*) and `\s` (*whitespace*):

- NEWLINE:

  - I'd like to use `\n`, but I have to use `.{1}$` instead
- WHITESPACE:

  - I'd like to use `\s`, but I have to use `\`  instead

Comment: What do you want to use newlines for? The `sed` expression won't see any newlines. As for the space, why would you want to use `\s` in the replacement text? You should be able to use just an ordinary space there.  If you want to appond something to the end of the line, just do `s/$/something/`, and `s/^/something/` for the start, and use `-e` to apply two separate expressions with a single `sed` command.

Comment: But if you want to change the name of files, using `rename` would be the better option.  See also [Why \*not\* parse \`ls\` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985)

Comment: Also note that if you have the names `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` in a directory, then `ls -xN` (using GNU `ls`) would produce a single line of output (`1  2  3  4`), not a column of four rows.

Comment: How about `printf 'Day %s.log\n' *` instead?

Comment: @Kusalananda   About *newlines* (`\n`): I was thinking that could be a nicer approach to tell `sed` to go to the end of the line.

Comment: @Kusalananda   About `rename`: I'm forcing to use `sed` because I want to learn it by doing :)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas <<How about printf 'Day %s.log\n' * instead?>> it works like a charm!! :) But I'm forcing to use `sed` to learn it by doing! ;) Anyway... Could you please elaborate on **why** it works with `printf`? What is `printf` doing?

Comment: @T.Caio One thing to learn is to use the right tool for the job. The `sed` editor is the right tool for processing lines of text. A filename is not a line of text as it may contain embedded newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU `sed` recognizes both `\n` and `\s`. However, `\s` means "any whitespace character", it matches at least a space, a newline (aka line feed), a tab, a form feed, a vertical tab and a carriage return, but likely more in your locale. It is equivalent to the standard `[[:space:]]` character class. Since it is not one character but many, it cannot be used on the right hand side of the replacement operator since it is ambiguous and `sed` wouldn't know what you want to insert. It works fine on the left hand side though:

```
$ printf '[space]: [tab]:\t[CR]:\r[FF]\f\n'
[FF]ce]: [tab]: [CR]:

$ printf '[space]: [tab]:\t[CR]:\r[FF]\f\n' | sed 's/\s/MATCH/g'
[space]:MATCH[tab]:MATCH[CR]:MATCH[FF]MATCH
$
```

Also, you can use a simple space, there is no need to escape it:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {1..4} | sed -E 's/^(.{1})/Day \1/'
Day 1
Day 2
Day 3
Day 4
```

Next, GNU `sed` recognizes newline characters just fine, I just don't understand how they are relevant here. The `$` means "match the end of the line". You could replace that with a `\n` if you want. For example:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {1..4} | sed -zE 's/(.)\n/\1.log\n/g'
1.log
2.log
3.log
4.log
```

It just doesn't seem relevant to the user case in your question. Finally, you could do the whole thing in a single operation:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {1..4} | sed -E 's/(.)/Day \1.log/'
Day 1.log
Day 2.log
Day 3.log
Day 4.log
```

On a final note, it is [almost never a good idea](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to parse the output of `ls` as that will break on even slightly strange file names. Not really relevant in the specific case you mention, but you should avoid it in general.

Comment: @[terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon)    Thanks for the detailed explanation and thank you for letting me know about (not) parsing `ls`'s output!